Limitations on input vectors representation of isotropic non-degenerate qudratic form?
Suppose we have quadratic form $F$ in vector space with dimension >10 and this form is isotropic (there is some non-null vector $v$ for which $F(v)=0$) and at the same time it is non-degenerate.
Question 1. Are there any limitations on vectors that could be represented by this quadratic form? I mean are there any vectors that could NOT be mapped in some value in $\mathbb{R}$ via such a form?
Question 2. Are there any values in $\mathbb{R}$ for which there are NO vectors to be mapped via this form to these values? And if they are, what are they or at least "how many" such points?
Thanks in advance for your answers and/or advices!

Please type in some quadratic forms in  2 or 3  or 4 variables, actual numbers as coefficients,  indicate your conclusions for your example forms. Things are quite different for 5 or more variables.

Thanks for your answer! I updated a question and it grew into two.. Sorry for this, but it is important too.
Regarding your clarifications. The dimension of vector space could be more than 10 in this case and we suppose that there are no limitations on the number of variables or coeffecients of the quadratic form. We just know that it is isotropic and non-degenerate. And want to know what cases are possible? Is it possible at all that some values in $\mathbb{R}$ is "not used" whatever vector is mapped, i.e. for what values d could be that  $F^{-1}(d)=\emptyset$?

Question 1 is nonsense. If $F : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ then, by definition of what a function is, $F$ can be applied to any vector.
For Question 2: If $F$ is nondegenerate and isotropic then there are vectors $v,v'$ such that $F(v) > 0$ and $F(v') < 0$. Now let $\alpha$ be an arbitrary real number.

If $\alpha \geq 0$ then $w = \sqrt{\frac\alpha{F(v)}}v$ represents $\alpha$:
$$
  F(w) = \left|\frac\alpha{F(v)}\right|F(v) = |\alpha| = \alpha.
$$
If $\alpha < 0$ then $w' = \sqrt{\frac\alpha{F(v')}}v'$ represents $\alpha$:
$$
  F(w') = \left|\frac\alpha{F(v')}\right|F(v') = -|\alpha| = \alpha.
$$

Thus $F$ represents all of $\mathbb R$.

Thank you very much for your answer!
Maybe the last clarification. WHY are there vectors ${v}$ and ${v}'$ such that $F(v) > 0$ and $F(v)' < 0$ giving the assumptions about the form above?
Thanks!

@PavelKu Every quadratic form has an orthogonal basis $B$ with respect to the bilinear form $$(v,w) \mapsto \frac12(F(v+w) - F(v) - F(w)). $$ For $F$ to be nondegenerate, we must have $F(e) \ne 0$ for every $e \in B$. If $F(e) > 0$ for all $e \in B$ then $F$ is positive definite, and if $F(e) < 0$ for all $e \in B$ then it is negative definite; so for indefinite $F$ we are forced to have $e, e' \in B$ such that $F(e) > 0$ and $F(e') < 0$.
